# How can I keep my web server's log files from becoming too large?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, nginx, logging, log-files

*Note: I am using Apache2 (on Linux), but I asked in a general sense (for Linux only) because I'd also like to know the "best" way to do accomplish this in a general (since I'm about to deploy  a large site on Nginx, or Cherokee).*

My log files are becoming huge after just a few weeks. I need to keep them around temporarily, but I'd like to delete entries that are older than 2 weeks, or so. Is this possible, and how do I do it?

Comment: Are you running on linux or windows?

Comment: @packs - Linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use logrotate. It rotates logs according to a configuration file for a specific service. It is usually run by cron on a daily basis.

An example of a config file for apache at `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2`

```
/var/log/apache2/*_log {
 daily
 rotate 31
 missingok
 compress
 delaycompress
 sharedscripts
 postrotate
  if [ -f "`. /etc/apache2/envvars ; echo ${APACHE_PID_FILE:-/var/run/apache2.pid}`" ]; then
     /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
  fi
 endscript
 }
```

This would:

- rotate logs everyday
- keep 31 rotated log files
- Compress rotated logs but keep latest rotated one uncompressed (delaycompress)
- Reload the process

If you dont want the process to be reloaded, then you should use `copytruncate`, which will copy the current content onto a new file, compress it and then truncate current logfile. In this case you dont need `sharedscripts`, `postrotate` and `endscript`.

Comment: In no way logrotate is a daemon, neither simpla nor complex one. :) "Normally, logrotate is run as a daily cron job" (c) manual

Comment: Sample cron command?

Comment: You can also give logrotate a 'size' parameter. It will then only rotate that log when the file is larger than the given filesize. It's useful for lesser used files, that you may not need/want to rotate every day.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical tool for handling logs is **logrotate**.